# Smoothly connecting circle centers

Tags: c#, math, geometry

I'm attempting to draw a path through the inside of a tube, along the center. The data I have to work with is the the center points of the circles describing the tube at the start and end of every turn in the pipe.

Drawing the path through the straight sections of pipe is trivial, but I'm not sure how to approach the bends. Any turn between two circles should be of constant radius. So I have access to two points on this circle, and the direction of of the circle line at that point.

Does anyone know how I would calculate the rest of the circle from this?

Edit:

Attached a photo-realistic sketch of a pipe.

[image: It's like I'm in the pipe!]

So pretend that curve isn't wobbly as hell, the blue lines indicate the circle, the red the center points, and the green the path through the center.

Comment: DrawArc takes the radius (as the bounding rectangle) and two angles: one for the start the other as the way the arc should cover. For a 90° turn that would be 90 or 270 depending on the direction..

Comment: Hm, that looks useful. I'm using another drawing tool unfortunately, so it wouldn't be compatible. I need to calculate the actual circle myself.

Comment: A little sketch would help. I'm not sure what you have and what you want.. Is it 3D? seen from top? What shapes do the bends have?

Comment: It is 3D, yeah. We can assume the bends are < 180 degrees, and they can turn in any direction, but before every change in the angle it's turning it/ radius there should be another center point.

Comment: Updated to add a sketch.

Comment: This is probably a pure math problem. You're looking for how to connect two lines with a curve.

Comment: OK, the circle will share its center with the black circles and its radius will be midway between theirs. In what form will you need it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **Clarification**

   tube has the same circular diameter everywhere so no distortion due to bending is present !!! input is 2 endpoints points (centers of tube) `P0,P1` and 2 vectors (normal/direction of tube) `N0,N1`

   [image: pipe bend]
2. **Solution**

   Use Interpolation cubic for example this one

   ```
   p(t)=a0+a1*t+a2*t*t+a3*t*t*t
   t=<0,1.0>
   ```

   so write equations for the known data, solve `a0,a1,a2,a3` coefficients for each axis you need (2D: `x,y`) and then you can get the center point and its normal in any point along the bend side which is what you need.

   Now some generic equations:

   ```
   p(t)=a0+a1*t+     a2*t*t+     a3*t*t*t // circle center position
   n(t)=   a1   +2.0*a2*t   +3.0*a3*t*t   // circle orientation
   ```

   - `p,n,a0,a1,a2,a3` are vectors !!!
   - `t` is scalar

   Now add the known data

   ```
   I. t=0 -> p(0)=P0
   P0=a0
   a0=P0

   II. t=0 -> n(0)=N0
   N0=a1
   a1=N0

   III. t=1 -> p(1)=P1
   P1=a0+a1+a2+a3
   P1=P0+N0+a2+a3
   a2=P1-P0-N0-a3

   IV. t=1 -> n(1)=N1
   N1=a1+2.0*a2+3.0*a3
   N1=N0+2.0*(P1-P0-N0-a3)+3.0*a3
   a3=N1+N0-2.0*(P1-P0)

   III.
   a2=P1-P0-N0-(N1+N0-2.0*(P1-P0))
   a2=P1-P0-N0-N1-N0+2.0*(P1-P0)
   a2=P1-P0-N1+2.0*(P1-P0-N0)
   a2=3.0*(P1-P0)-N1-2.0*N0
   ```

   So if I did not make any silly mistake then coefficients are:

   ```
   a0=P0
   a1=N0
   a2=3.0*(P1-P0)-N1-2.0*N0
   a3=N1+N0-2.0*(P1-P0)
   ```

   So now just encode generic equations into some function with input parameter `t` and output `p(t)` and `n(t)` and/or render circle or tube segment and the call this in for loop for example like this:

   ```
   for (t=0.0;t<=1.0;t+=0.1) f(t);
   ```

**[edit1] C++ implementation**

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void glCircle3D(double *pos,double *nor,double r,bool _fill)
    {
    int i,n=36;
    double a,da=divide(pi2,n),p[3],dp[3],x[3],y[3];
         if (fabs(nor[0]-nor[1])>1e-6) vector_ld(x,nor[1],nor[0],nor[2]);
    else if (fabs(nor[0]-nor[2])>1e-6) vector_ld(x,nor[2],nor[1],nor[0]);
    else if (fabs(nor[1]-nor[2])>1e-6) vector_ld(x,nor[0],nor[2],nor[1]);
    else                       vector_ld(x,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    vector_mul(x,x,nor);
    vector_mul(y,x,nor);
    vector_len(x,x,r);
    vector_len(y,y,r);
    if (_fill)
        {
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        glVertex3dv(pos);
        }
    else glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for (a=0.0,i=0;i<=n;i++,a+=da)
        {
        vector_mul(dp,x,cos(a)); vector_add(p,pos,dp);
        vector_mul(dp,y,sin(a)); vector_add(p,p  ,dp);
        glVertex3dv(p);
        }
    glEnd();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void tube(double *P0,double *N0,double *P1,double *N1,double R)
    {
    int i;
    double a0[3],a1[3],a2[3],a3[3],p[3],n[3],t,tt,ttt;
    // compute coefficients
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
        a0[i]=P0[i];
        a1[i]=N0[i];
        a2[i]=(3.0*(P1[i]-P0[i]))-N1[i]-(2.0*N0[i]);
        a3[i]=N1[i]+N0[i]-2.0*(P1[i]-P0[i]);
        }
    // step through curve from t=0 to t=1
    for (t=0.0;t<=1.0;t+=0.02)
        {
        tt=t*t;
        ttt=tt*t;
        // compute circle position and orientation
        for (i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
            p[i]=a0[i]+(a1[i]*t)+(a2[i]*tt)+(a3[i]*ttt);
            n[i]=a1[i]+(2.0*a2[i]*t)+(3.0*a3[i]*tt);
            }
        // render it
        glCircle3D(p,n,R,false);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void test()
    {
    // tube parameters
    double P0[3]={-1.0, 0.0, 0.0},N0[3]={+1.0,-1.0, 0.0},p[3];
    double P1[3]={+1.0,+1.0, 0.0},N1[3]={ 0.0,+1.0, 0.0};
    // just normalize normals to size 3.1415...
    vector_len(N0,N0,M_PI);
    vector_len(N1,N1,M_PI);
    // draw normals to visula confirmation of tube direction
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0); vector_add(p,P0,N0); glVertex3dv(P0); glVertex3dv(p);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0); vector_add(p,P1,N1); glVertex3dv(P1); glVertex3dv(p);
    glEnd();
    // render tube
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0); tube(P0,N0,P1,N1,0.2);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Visually it best looks when normals are of size `M_PI (3.1415...)` this is how it looks for the code above:

[image: pipe C++]

the code of mine use mine vector library so you just need to code functions like:

```
vector_ld(a,x,y,z); //a[]={ x,y,z }
vector_mul(a,b,c);  //a[]=b[] x c[]
vector_mul(a,b,c);  //a[]=b[] * c
vector_add(a,b,c);  //a[]=b[] + c[]
vector_sub(a,b,c);  //a[]=b[] - c[]
vector_len(a,b,c);  //a[]=b[]*  c / |b[]|
```

which is easy (hope I did not forget to copy something ...)...

Comment: @djcmm476 wow you accepted it sooner then I finneshed the edditing :) added C++ code with OpenGL visualisation ....

Comment: @djcmm476 if you have specific demands on the curve shape then just add appropriate equation for known data (instead of useless one or add another coefficient like a4,... so you have equal number of equations and coefficients). the range of t I choose 0-1 only to make the equations simple to solve

Comment: also you can compute the direction geometrically by substracting p(t)-p(t-dt) last two points ... which would looks even better I think

Comment: I mean the amount of work you put in you entirely deserve the accepted answer. ¬_¬ I have a couple of small differences in mine, but I can tweak this to make it work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @djcmm476 most of it was already done the only real work was to draw the first image in paint :)