# Model 3D spring from points

Tags: c, opengl, modeling

I have generated points like this and now I what to connect all these points into one model - spring. How can I achieve this? I've tried iterating through each point and build it from polygons or triangles but I have failed.

I have set of rings where each ring was build from points which coords I have.

[image]

Comment: So [GLE](https://linas.org/gle/)-style [helix output](https://linas.org/gle/helixtex.gif)?

Comment: see [Morph a cube to coil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35055911/2521214)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to treat these as generalized cylinders and tessellate a triangle mesh. This can be done by sweeping a circle along the path. Some of the details are tricky since undefined tangents can lead to unexpected twists in your triangle mesh. You might want to study the GLE library or the `TubeGeometry` implementation in ThreeJS.

For simplestic rendering, note that OpenGL has `GL_LINE_STRIP`. It also has `glLineWidth`, although many platforms have a max width of 1. You would need to take care to use separate draw calls for seperate springs, otherwise they'll be connected.