# Generating 3D Cylinder with Rotationmatrix

Tags: c++, 3d

I am trying to create a cylinder in 3D space.
I get a start and endpoint in 3D and to place the vertices, I need to create 2 circles for the bottom and the top of the cylinder. 
I thought about making a vector u with coordinates (1,0,0) and calculate a direction vector dir = end - start.
Now I make the cross product to get a vector w = u x dir:
this way I am 90 degrees away from the dir vector with w. The problem is, how do I calculate the next position w' with an arbitrary angle between w and w'.
I Read a lot about rotation matrix, and that i can rotate around X-Axis with something like:

```
Rx(angle) =   
(1   0          0          )  
(0   cos(angle) -sin(angle))  
(0   sin(angle) cos(angle) )
```

but the direction can be something like (1.442, -3.22, 7.23). So it isn't always the x-axis but maybe I need to rotate for every new w' in every axis. And I don't know how to figure out what angle I need to calculate, how to calculate and which angle belongs to witch rotation matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **basis vectors** for this (which can be encoded into **transform matrix**).

So let assume you got:

`p0[3],p1[3]` - **3D** center points `(x,y,z)` of your cylinder bases

`r` - radius

To construct **transform matrix** you need

`O[3]` - origin position

`X[3],Y[3],Z[3]` - basis vectors

So you can exploit **cross product** to get perpendicular vectors:

```
O = p0;
Z = p1-p0;
Y = (1.0,0.0,0.0);
if (|dot(Y,Z)/|Z||>0.75) Y = (0.0,1.0,0.0); // this just make sure Z and Y are not parallel
X = cross(Y,Z);
Y = cross(Z,X);
X = r*X/|X|;
Y = r*Y/|Y|;
```

Now construct your **4x4 transform matrix** `M` or use the `X,Y,Z,O` directly to compute the vertexes:

base0:

```
x=cos(a);
y=sin(a);
z=0.0;
```

base1:

```
x=cos(a);
y=sin(a);
z=1.0;
```

Where `a = <0.0,2.0*PI>` is angle. `XY` plane is parallel to bases and z is cylinder axis. To convert these `(x,y,z)` to World coordinates use:

```
(x',y',z') = M * (x,y,z)
```

Which can be done natively in **OpenGL** by using `M` as part of `GL_MODELVIEW` or do this instead:

```
x' = O[0] + x*X[0] + y*Y[0] + z*Z[0];
y' = O[1] + x*X[1] + y*Y[1] + z*Z[1];
z' = O[2] + x*X[2] + y*Y[2] + z*Z[2];
```

Take a look at related QAs:

- [my simple C++ glCircle3D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25182327/2521214)
- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)