# Creating quaternion from direction and up vectors for rotation matrix

Tags: c#, math, directx, light

How to calculate rotation matrix based on cone direction? I have a spotlight defined like this:
[image]

I'm creating vertices array for a cone to draw spot light shape and then I'm creating a buffer (line loop mode):

```
private static float[] createConeVerticesArray(float radius,
                                               float height,
                                               int segments)
{
    Array<Float> verticesArray = new Array<>();

    float angle = 2 * MathUtils.PI / segments;
    float cos = MathUtils.cos(angle);
    float sin = MathUtils.sin(angle);
    float cx = radius, cy = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < segments; i++)
    {
        verticesArray.add(cx);
        verticesArray.add(cy);
        verticesArray.add(height);

        verticesArray.add(0f);
        verticesArray.add(0f);
        verticesArray.add(0f);

        verticesArray.add(cx);
        verticesArray.add(cy);
        verticesArray.add(height);

        float temp = cx;
        cx = cos * cx - sin * cy;
        cy = sin * temp + cos * cy;

        verticesArray.add(cx);
        verticesArray.add(cy);
        verticesArray.add(height);
    }
    verticesArray.add(cx);
    verticesArray.add(cy);
    verticesArray.add(height);

    cx = radius;
    cy = 0;
    verticesArray.add(cx);
    verticesArray.add(cy);
    verticesArray.add(height);

    float[] result = new float[verticesArray.size];
    for(int i = 0; i < verticesArray.size; i++)
    {
        result[i] = verticesArray.get(i);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Next step I'm creating three spot lights like this which represents 3 rotations around each axis:

```
this.spotLights.add(new CSpotLight(
            new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f), //Color
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, 5000f), //Position
            1f, //Intensity
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, -1f), //Direction
            15f, //Inner angle
            30f, //Outer angle
            4000f, //Radius
            1f)); //Attenuation
    this.spotLights.add(new CSpotLight(
            new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f),
            new Vector3(0f, 5000f, 0f),
            1f,
            new Vector3(0f, -1f, 0f),
            15f,
            30f,
            4000f,
            1f));
    this.spotLights.add(new CSpotLight(
            new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f),
            new Vector3(5000f, 0f, 0f),
            1f,
            new Vector3(-1f, 0f, 0f),
            15f,
            30f,
            4000f,
            1f));
```

And then I'm calculating quaternion for each spot light to create rotation matrix for model matrix (just for vertex shader purpose):

```
private static Quaternion quaternionLookRotation(Vector3 direction, Vector3 up)
{
    Vector3 vector = Pools.obtain(Vector3.class).set(direction).nor();
    Vector3 vector2 = Pools.obtain(Vector3.class).set(up).crs(vector).nor();
    Vector3 vector3 = Pools.obtain(Vector3.class).set(vector).crs(vector2);

    float m00 = vector2.x;
    float m01 = vector2.y;
    float m02 = vector2.z;
    float m10 = vector3.x;
    float m11 = vector3.y;
    float m12 = vector3.z;
    float m20 = vector.x;
    float m21 = vector.y;
    float m22 = vector.z;

    Pools.free(vector);
    Pools.free(vector2);
    Pools.free(vector3);

    float num8 = (m00 + m11) + m22;
    Quaternion quaternion = Pools.obtain(Quaternion.class);
    if (num8 > 0f)
    {
        float num = (float) Math.sqrt(num8 + 1f);
        quaternion.w = num * 0.5f;
        num = 0.5f / num;
        quaternion.x = (m12 - m21) * num;
        quaternion.y = (m20 - m02) * num;
        quaternion.z = (m01 - m10) * num;
        return quaternion;
    }
    if ((m00 >= m11) && (m00 >= m22))
    {
        float num7 = (float) Math.sqrt(((1f + m00) - m11) - m22);
        float num4 = 0.5f / num7;
        quaternion.x = 0.5f * num7;
        quaternion.y = (m01 + m10) * num4;
        quaternion.z = (m02 + m20) * num4;
        quaternion.w = (m12 - m21) * num4;
        return quaternion;
    }
    if (m11 > m22)
    {
        float num6 = (float) Math.sqrt(((1f + m11) - m00) - m22);
        float num3 = 0.5f / num6;
        quaternion.x = (m10+ m01) * num3;
        quaternion.y = 0.5f * num6;
        quaternion.z = (m21 + m12) * num3;
        quaternion.w = (m20 - m02) * num3;
        return quaternion;
    }
    float num5 = (float) Math.sqrt(((1f + m22) - m00) - m11);
    float num2 = 0.5f / num5;
    quaternion.x = (m20 + m02) * num2;
    quaternion.y = (m21 + m12) * num2;
    quaternion.z = 0.5f * num5;
    quaternion.w = (m01 - m10) * num2;
    return quaternion;
}

this.rotMatrix.set(quaternionLookRotation(
                spotLight.getDirection(),
                new Vector3(0, 1, 0)));
```

Two rotations from three works perfectly. The problem appears only in the third rotation axis which should faced point (0, 0, 0):
[image]

Comment: Decide OpenGL or DirectX. The question cannot be about both. Seems like "C#" doesn't it?

Comment: Why cannot be about both? Question is about calculating matrices and quaternions which is represented by float buffers in DirectX and OpenGL in the same way.

Comment: So the question doesn't apply to any of them? [tag:Opengl] is for questions related to the OpenGL API and [tag:directx] is for questions related to the directx API. Mathematics questions are neither about one nor the other.

Comment: @Dragomirus on top of that Dx and OpenGL uses different notations for transformation so equations for OpenGL will not work in DX and vice versa they usually inverted however for complicated stuff its not always true ... I think what you want is this: [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) so just use your cone direction as one babsis vector position and origin and the missing 2 vectors [compute by exploiting cross product from the direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41813188/2521214)....

Comment: and do nto forget to transpose the resulting matrix as I am using OpenGL conventions

Comment: You've complicated this simple problem. It's all about quaternions and simple math - see the result below and this piece of code works in OpenGL and DirectX. You jus have to implement Vector3 and Quaternion class and then create rotation matrix from quaternion. Thanks to guys from gamedev.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final code which works fine in any cases:

```
private static Quaternion rotationBetweenTwoVectors(Vector3 vec1, Vector3 vec2)
{
    Quaternion result = Pools.obtain(Quaternion.class);
    Vector3 u = Pools.obtain(Vector3.class).set(vec1).nor();
    Vector3 v = Pools.obtain(Vector3.class).set(vec2).nor();
    float dot = u.dot(v);

    if(dot < -0.999999)
    {
        Vector3 tmp1 = Pools.obtain(Vector3.class).set(Vector3.X).crs(u);
        if(tmp1.len() < 0.000001)
        {
            tmp1.set(Vector3.Y).crs(u);
        }
        tmp1.nor();
        result.setFromAxisRad(tmp1, MathUtils.PI).nor();
        Pools.free(tmp1);
    }
    else if(dot > 0.999999)
    {
        result.idt();
    }
    else
    {
        result.setFromCross(u, v);
    }
    Pools.free(u);
    Pools.free(v);

    return result;
}
```

Where setFromCross calculates axis from cross product of two vectors and angle like this:

```
final float dot = MathUtils.clamp(Vector3.dot(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2), -1f, 1f);
final float angle = (float)Math.acos(dot);
```

Hope this will helps somebody :)