# Calculating cylinder surface points from centreline

Tags: math, 3d, geometry

I have two points  A = (x0, y0, z0) and B = (x1, y1, z1) giving the centreline for a cylinder.
I want to add a series of surface points with radius r from centreline, perpendicular to the line AB, to get a point cloud of the cylinder surface.

How can I best get a code that calculates points with r distance from centerline, perpendicular to AB, 360 degrees around the centreline, along the distance of AB.

Comment: The first step is to find a vector perpendicular to AB. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Not 100% sure. We can get the AB vector by (x1-x0, y1-y0, z1-z0), and then a perpendicular vector would have a cross product of zero? But I don't get how to come up with a solution for getting perpendicular vectors 360 degrees around the centreline.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating 3D Cylinder with Rotationmatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494329/generating-3d-cylinder-with-rotationmatrix)

Answer (score 0):

We have the vector from **A** to **B**, call it **C**. We can normalise it: **c** = **C**/|**C**|

The first step is to find a vector perpendicular to **c**. We pick one of the basis vectors, **x**, **y** or **z**. (If the dot product reveals that we picked one close or equal to **c**, we pick one of the other two instead.) Suppose we have picked **x**. We find the component of **x** in the direction of **c**:

(**x•c**)**c**

and subtract it from **x** to get a vector perpendicular to **c**:

**J** = **x** - (**x•c**)**c**

which we can then normailse to get **j**. Now use the cross product to get another unit vector, perpendicular to both **c** and **j**:

**k** = **c** × **j**

Now we can pick any angle θ and get a point on the unit circle centered on the origin and normal to **c**:

**p** = cos(θ)**j** + sin(θ)**k**

If we choose a point **D** on the line between **A** and **B**, we can find a point on the inot circle centered on **D** and normal to **c**:

**q** = cos(θ)**j** + sin(θ)**k** + **D**

Now vary **D** from **A** to **B**, and θ from 0 to 2π, and you're done.