# Getting 3D Tube surface coordinates along a set of given coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, geometry

I searched through some interpolating approaches but I didn't find a suitable answer for my problem.

**The Task**

I have many different cells that have different positions at different time steps. Now I need to get the surface coordinates of a cylinder along these coordinates of one cell, like a tube around these cell coordinates. So I have some coordinates and want to get all coordinates around the polyline in a specific radius that the coordinates would build, if connecting them. Like a geometrical cylinder around them.

Let's say I have these coordinates:

```
    x      y      z
302,123 65,211  24,095
303,845 64,304  19,663
307,306 60,477  16,392
310,868 52,443  9,462
308,443 47,625  1,5
```

I want my coordinates to be in a grid with a distance of 1, so I rounded them:

```
 x   y   z
302 65  24
304 64  20
307 60  16
311 52  9
308 48  2
```

So when connecting these points I think it should create many interpolated points, which only can be on coordinates in my grid space. So if for example my space for x, y, z is 1 and if connecting for example (0,0) and (2,1) in 2D I cannot set a point at (1,0.5) but at (1,1) or (1,0). The cylinder should have the radius 3 around the coordinates for an example. So I would add a pattern around my coordinates and the interpolated coordinates. In the 2D example I would get for the set `[(0,0), (1,0), (2,1)]-->[(0,3), (0, -3), (1,3), (1, -3), (2,4), (2, -2)]`. Is there a simple/good way to do this in 3D space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smoothly connecting circle centers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178181/smoothly-connecting-circle-centers)

Comment: Your question is very unclear at multiple points, and it might even be an XY problem. Do you have a definition for which integers to use along a trajectory between two points? How would you generalize your 2d example for generating new points? I find it hard to believe that an unorganized bag of extra coordinates that you're generating benefits you in any reasonable way. What is your ultimate goal with these coordinates?